# How to rename logical file names in recovery pending database that cannot be recovered?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here's the situation:

- Someone renamed database `A` to `A_old` in SSMS
- They did not rename the physical nor logical file; physical file was renamed somehow to `A_old.mdf`
- They then created a new database called `A` that has `A.mdf` as filename
- However `A_old` database is now in recovery mode because it still has *logical* file name `A.mdf`

I tried to rename the logical file with a script (`ALTER DATABASE ... MODIFY FILE`), getting and not getting the database offline, as admin in SSMS, but still getting an error:

> Database 'A_OLD' cannot be opened due to inaccessible files or
> insufficient memory or disk space.

There is disk space and memory. If I set offline/online this does not work, because it keeps trying to attach the database to the new one's file which is using it. Also tried to copy the mdf file and manually attach it using SSMS but it does not work because it looks for the file without the `_old` suffix.

I'm running out of ideas. Is there any way to recover this database?

Comment: I don't believe the problem is related to the *logical file name* since the FILENAME property is the one that references the file on the disk. I just renamed the logical file name of a database and it's still working fine.

Comment: It seem you brought SQL Server down and renamed A.md to A_Old.mdf. Now after you started SQL Server SQL Server database A is not finding it's datafile that's why it's giving you this error.

Comment: @Ronaldo you're right, it was the physical file pointing to `A`. They actually renamed the files on disk with the server offline but did not update the properties in SSMS.

Comment: @RajeshRanjan correct, this is what actually happened.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to have both databases co-exist then I would try the following:

1. Take both the `A` database and `A_old` database offline if possible.
2. Make copies or temporarily move their MDF and LDF files. (This is a precautionary measure and may be a little overkill.)
3. Drop the `A_old` database.
4. Put back the MDF and LDF files of both databases.
5. Turn `A` back online (and make sure it's still working properly).
6. Attach a database and select the MDF and LDF for `A_old` which if I understand you correctly is now called "A_old.mdf" (note the LDF file will need to have a different name than the new `A` database's LDF file too).
7. Verify `A_old` is working properly now.

Comment: `A` is live in production. Is there a way to do this without getting it offline? Also they don't need to co-exist, if I could access `A_old` on another (dev) server it would be enough.

Comment: @evilmandarine The thing I'm unsure of / worried about is if you try dropping `A_old` if it'll remove the MDF / LDF of the production `A` database (which is why my precautionary step 2 says to move / copy both databases' files). I believe it'll try (because that's the logical path). It may error out if `A` is currently connected to / in use, or it may succeed, I'm not sure. So I'd try to get a maintenance window off-hours from production, so you could follow the steps I mentioned. Of course once you have `A_old` database successfully dropped, you don't have to re-attach it to the same server.

Comment: Yep, I think I'll need the maintenance window. I was trying to avoid that at all costs because this is a different, not technical kind of issue now (tight production schedule).

Comment: @evilmandarine Gotcha, yea I've been there. Usually a few minutes of downtime trumps risk of data loss and longer downtime, at least when explained to sensible people lol. All in all, the above process should be accomplishable in about 10 minutes, but obviously ask for a longer maintenance window just in case. Also this is where things like Availability Groups are nice because you can failover to a secondary server, and fix the previous primary, then fail back over if needed, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As I only needed the data I ended up managing to get it on the same server running this command (the SSMS Attach... did not work but this is the script it generated):

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [A_OLD_Copy] ON 
( FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\A_OLD.mdf' ),
( FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\A_log_OLD.ldf' )
 FOR ATTACH
GO
```

Comment: Ah that's true. To get access to the data now, you could attach the files as a new database. Cleaning up the old `A_old` database will likely require more of a process though, but that sounds like it's secondary to your goal anyway. Good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just change the path to that file

```sql
ALTER DATABASE A_Old
MODIFY FILE (
  NAME = [A.mdf],
  FILENAME = 'C:\Whatever Path Here\A_Old.mdf'
);
```

You can also specify a new logical name for the file, although this is not actually necessary

```sql
ALTER DATABASE A_Old
MODIFY FILE (
  NAME = [A.mdf],
  NEWNAME = [A_Old.mdf],
  FILENAME = 'C:\Whatever Path Here\A_Old.mdf'
);
```

You may need to set the database `OFFLINE` first.